# Variables in Julia change their type while being constructed

Tags: constructor, julia

I am brand new in Julia programming, and am facing a baffling situation, which I simply can't understand.  So, this is what I want to do: I have two structs: `Shoe` and `Person`, where `Person` contains a `Shoe`

This is how the code looks:

```
struct Shoe
  size  :: Int64
  brand :: String
end

struct Person
  age  :: Int64
  shoe :: Shoe

  function Person(a::Int64, s::Shoe)
    age  = a
    shoe = s
  end

  function Person()
    age  = 33
    shoe = Shoe(17,"Nike")
  end
end

ian = Person(17, Shoe(32,"Puma"))
tom = Person()

println(typeof(ian))
println(typeof(tom))
```

To my utter surprise, `ian` and `tom`, which I try to define as persons, turn out to be shoes.  Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just out of curiosity, are you following the "Julia Quick Syntax Reference" book ? There is a very similar example there...

Answer (score 9):

`function Person`, being a constructor for the struct `Person`, should return an instance of `struct Person`, but because its last line is `shoe = Shoe(17,"Nike")` (and because assignment is an expression that evaluates to whatever `shoe` becomes), it ends up returning that `Shoe`.

Constructors should call the built-in `new` constructor:

```
struct Person
  age  :: Int64
  shoe :: Shoe

  # This function is redundant since
  # it does exactly the same thing as the `new` constructor
  function Person(a::Int64, s::Shoe)
    age  = a
    shoe = s

    new(age, shoe)
  end

  function Person()
    age  = 33
    shoe = Shoe(17,"Nike")

    new(age, shoe)
  end
end
```

---

AFAIK, you don't need to use constructors unless they're doing input validation. You *do* need a constructor to ensure that it's impossible to construct a `Person` with negative `age`, for example, because `Int64` can be negative. (You could ensure that `age >= 0` by using `UInt64`, too. But then you'd have to write `17` in hexadecimal (`0x11`) all the time, which is kind of annoying)

I'd write it like this:

```
struct Person
  age  :: Int64
  shoe :: Shoe

  function Person(age::Int64, shoe::Shoe)
    @assert age >= 0

    new(age, shoe)
  end
end

# Put other constructors outside
Person() = Person(33, Shoe(17, "Nike"))
```

Example:

```
julia> Person(-1, Shoe(0, "Hello"))
ERROR: AssertionError: age >= 0
Stacktrace:
 [1] Person(age::Int64, shoe::Shoe)
   @ Main ./REPL[3]:6
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1

julia> Person()
Person(33, Shoe(17, "Nike"))
```

Comment: Wow cool, thanks a lot :-)